# Propagate JavaScript mouse event(s) from one element to another element?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, dom-events

I am using a HTML `div` element as a tool tip for a `canvas`, i.e. the `div` shall follow the mouse's motions as the mouse pointer moves across the `canvas` element.

This works – almost.  The tool top is south-east of the mouse pointer, and when the pointer is moving south-east-ish then it may happen that the pointer moves onto the `div` element so that no more mouse-move events are reaching `canvas`.  This is only resolves when the mouse is further moved beyond the `div` which makes the `div` jump in an ugly way to adjust to that position.

How can I avoid these jumps and implement that the `div` is "transparent" for the mouse?

Usual bubbling up does not work because a `canvas` cannot hold children; at least when I am adding children to a `canvas` they won't be displayed.

No external modules like jQuery or whatever are used / available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the div.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, neither `el.pointerevents = "none";` nor `el.pointerEvents = "none";` where `el` is the respective DOM `div` element.

Comment: ...ah got it.  It's element of `style`, not of the element itself: `el.style.pointerEvents = "none";` Thanks.

Comment: Well it does link to CSS documentation. ;)

Comment: What if I need a click event on the div and a mousemove event on the canvas?